# Are There Easy Ways To Print Data on Specific Area

Tags: .net, vb.net, printing

I'd like to print some data to specific area on A4 paper. Are there any easy way to do like that? It's very difficult for me to find coordinate of `X` and `Y`. Below is my sample code in VB.NET to print the data:

```
Private Sub PrintDocument1_PrintPage(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs) Handles PrintDocument1.PrintPage    
        e.Graphics.DrawString("My text", f_en, Brushes.Black, 410, 942)
        ...
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the location you want to draw on in milimeters you may try this:

```
e.Graphics.PageUnit =  GraphicsUnit.Millimeter;
```